# Alternating sums of a list

Tags: python, alternating

9.Write a program that accepts 9 integers from the user and stores them in a list. Next, compute the alternating sum of all of the elements in the list. For example, if the user enters
1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11
then it computes
1 – 4 + 9 – 16 + 9 – 7 + 4 – 9 + 11 = –2

```
myList = []
value = None
count = 0
while count != 9:
  value = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
  myList.append(value)
  count = count + 1
  if count == 9:
    break
print(myList)
def newList(mylist):
  return myList[0] - myList[1] + myList[2] - myList[3] + myList[4] - myList[5] + myList[6] - myList[7] + myList[8]
x = newList(myList)
print(x)
```

My code returns the correct answer, but I need it to print out the actual alternating sums as in the example.  I have been stuck on this for a while.  I am having a mental block on this and havent been able to find anything similar to this online.
I appreciate any help or tips.
Also, this is python 3.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem again?

Comment: I get the right answer (-2) from the example numbers, but I need it to also print out the actual equation, not just the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]
start1=0
start2=1
sum1=0
first_list=[a[i] for i in range(start1,len(a),2)]
second_list=[a[i] for i in range(start2,len(a),2)]
string=''
for i,j in zip(first_list,second_list):
    string+=str(i)+'-'+str(j)+'+'
string.rstrip('+')
print('{}={}'.format(string,str(sum(first_list)-sum(second_list))))
```

Output

```
1-4+9-16+9-7+4-9+=-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
positives = myList[::2]
negatives = myList[1::2]
result = sum(positives) - sum(negatives)
print ("%s = %d" % (" + ".join(["%d - %d" % (p, n) for p, n in zip(positives, negatives)]), result))
```

I'll explain what I'm doing here. The first two lines are taking slices of your list. I take every other number in `myList` starting from 0 for `positives` and starting from 1 for `negatives`. From there, finding the result of the alternating sum is just a matter of taking the sum of `positives` and subtracting the sum of `negatives` from it.

The final line is somewhat busy. Here I zip positives and negatives together which produces a list of 2-tuples where of the form `(positive, negative)` and then I use string formatting to produce the `p - n` form. From there I use `join` to join these together with the plus sign, which produces `p0 - n0 + p1 - n1 + p2 - n2...`. Finally, I use string formatting again to get it in the form of `p0 - n0 + p1 - n1 + p2 - n2 ... = result`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you did but place it in a print statement

```
print(myList[0] + " - " + myList[1] + " + " + myList[2] + " - " + myList[3] + " + " + myList[4] + " - " + myList[5] + " + " + myList[6] + " - " + myList[7] + " + " + myList[8] + " = " + x)
```

Its not perfectly clean, but it follows your logic, so your teacher won't know you got your solution from someone else.

Comment: This doesn't run in Python 3.

Comment: how come it doesnt work in python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following would work:

```
def sumList(theList):
    value = 0
    count = 0
    steps = ""
    for i in theList:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            value += i
            steps += " + " + str(i)
        else:
            value -= i
            steps += " - " + str(i)
        count += 1
    print(steps[3:])
    return value


print(sumList(myList))
```

It alternates between `+` and `-` by keeping track of the place in the list and using the modulus operator. Then it calculates the value and appends to a string to show the steps which were taken.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like below once your 9 or more numbers list is ready

```
st = ''
sum = 0

for i, v in enumerate(myList):
    if i == 0:
        st += str(v)
        sum += v
    elif i % 2 == 0:
        st += "+" + str(v)
        sum += v
    else:
        st += "-" + str(v)
        sum -= v

print("%s=%d" % (st, sum))
```

It prints : `1-4+9-16+9-7+4-9+11=-2`

Comment: This works great.  We still havent learned formatting with % in depth but this works for my purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know! Happy coding